# How to say (\w+\W+) times 4 in regex (R gsub)

Tags: r, regex, gsub

(In R gsub(),) I need to capture the four words occurring after a particular phrase in a bigger string. Building on the wisdom offered [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/near.html), I came up with: `^.*\\b(particular phrase)\\W+(\\w+\\W+\\w+\\W+\\w+\\W+\\w+).*$`

For example:

```
this_txt <- "Blah blah particular phrase Extract These Words Please for the blah blah. Ignore blah this other stuff blah blah, blah."
this_pattern <- "^.*\\b(particular phrase)\\W+(\\w+\\W+\\w+\\W+\\w+\\W+\\w+).*$"
gsub(this_pattern, "\\2", this_txt, ignore.case = T)
# [1] "Extract These Words Please"
```

But the repetition of `\\w+\\W+` in the pattern is pretty unseemly. Surely there is a better way. I thought `^.*\\b(particular phrase)\\W+(\\w+\\W+){4}.*$`
might work, but it doesn't.

Comment: [It does work](https://regex101.com/r/soTiU3/1), but does end with a `\W`. You just needed to capture with another group and change the inner to a non capturing group.

Comment: `.*\\bparticular phrase((?:\\W+\\w+){4}).*` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^.*\b(particular phrase)\W+((?:\w+\W+){3}\w+).*$
```

In R,

```
this_pattern <- "^.*\\b(particular phrase)\\W+((?:\\w+\\W+){3}\\w+).*$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1CBp7U/1)

`(\w+\W+\w+\W+\w+\W+\w+)` is replaced with `((?:\w+\W+){3}\w+)`. The `((?:\w+\W+){3}\w+)` is a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (`(...)`) that contains two subpatterns:

- `(?:\w+\W+){3}` - a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) matching three repetitions of

  - `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
  - `\W+` - 1 or more non-word chars
- `\w+` - 1 or mor word chars.